# Google repo, run --depth=1 when pulling

Tags: python, android, git, repo

I want to download only the latest commit of the lineage OS source code, and repo doesn't accept --depth=1.
I've tried to edit the python code for repo but i didn't succeed

Comment: oh, i meant depth=1

Comment: @torek i corrected my mistake

Comment: You've expressed your goal: clone with `--depth 1`. You haven't yet expressed your *question about Python programming*, if that's what you have here (you tagged this with [tag:python]).

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the `repo init` command doesn't accept a `--depth` option, is that correct? According to [its docs](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo),

> Repo complements Git by simplifying work

and it would seem that's one of the simplifications it makes. Their toolchain hides all the scary parts of Git that require effort and understanding rather than just cut-and-paste imitation.

If you want to upgrade the `repo` command itself to expose more of the underlying Git options and are asking for help here, [`repo` itself is Git managed](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/), say `git format-patch` on the changes you've made and ask about them: post the changes, link to why and how you thought they'd work, show what happened instead.

Comment: no, what i mean is when you run git clone or git pull --depth=1 gets used to save data when downloading, but im asking how to add that functionality to repo